# Not showing like preview in Enfold theme Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, caching, cpanel

This is showing when I publish in the live site. But my preview is showing something beautiful. When I checked the preview's network in debug mood and live site's network in the debug mood I found the live network is not using latest CSS file. How to solve it?

[image: Showing in the live preview even in the website]

Comment: Did you find a solution to your issue? I am encountering exactly the same thing.

Comment: Clear the cache please and try to open in a new browser.